# Why sql executes the statements after raising the error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, raiseerror

I have written this code. The problem is that after raising error it still hits executes the code after where it raises the error.

Begin Try
Begin transaction

```
  Declare @Days int
  Set @Days= (Select Days from Days where IsActive=1)

  declare @Message varchar(100)
  Set @Message= 'The difference between current date and expiry date must be equal or greater than '+ Convert(varchar,@Days)

  if(datediff(dd, GETDATE(), convert(date,dbo.Func_Base64Decode(@ExpiryDate))) >= @Days)
  Begin
        Set @ErrorMsgType= 0

  End
  Else
  Begin
        Set @ErrorMsgType= 2
        Raiserror(@Message, 16,10);
        return
  End

  //Some insertion code after it.


commit transaction
End Try
```

in catch block:

```
Begin Catch


            if(@ErrorMsgType = 1)
            Begin
                Raiserror('Opening time cannot be smaller than expiry time', 16,10);
            End
            Else
            Begin
                Set @Message= (Select ERROR_MESSAGE())
                Raiserror(@Message, 16,10);

            End
            RollBack Transaction

    End Catch
```

why?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: severity with 16 is good but still it executes

Comment: So just to understand the problem, when you run this which error message do you see printed out?

Answer (score 0):

```
Return
```

did the trick. Putting return after the RAISERROR did the trick.